# Displaying number of items per category in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP/MYSQL languages and would like to know if anyone could tell me how to display number of items next to the categories I have given below.

Example,

Art (5) 
Drama (2)
Music (5)
Fiction (4)
Computer (5)

And, here is my php code;

index.php

```
<?php 

$dbh=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die ('Cannot connedt to the Database' .mysql_errno()); 
mysql_select_db("booksdb");


?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Select a Company</title>

</head>

<body>


<?php 

$res_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bookcatname ORDER BY category ASC");

while ($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_query) )
{
  echo '<a href="page.php?cat_id='.$category['cat_id'].'">'.$category['category'].'</a><br />';
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

page.php

```
<?php 

$dbh=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die ('Cannot connect to the Database' .mysql_errno()); 
mysql_select_db("booksdb");

if ( empty($_GET['cat_id']) )
{
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit();
}



$getCats = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE cat_id = '".intval($_GET['cat_id'])."'");

echo '<ul>';

while ( $book = mysql_fetch_assoc($getCats) )
{
   echo '<li>'.$book['title'].'<br />'.$book['author'].'<br />'.'</li><br />';
}

echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Here are the tables;

```
table name - bookcatname

+----+--------+----------+
| id | cat_id | category |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 |      1 | Art      |
|  2 |      2 | Drama    |
|  3 |      3 | Music    |
|  4 |      4 | Fiction  |
|  5 |      5 | Computer |
+----+--------+----------+


table name - books

+----+--------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+
| id | cat_id | title                           | author                |
+----+--------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+
|  1 |      1 | Color and Light                 | James Gurney          |
|  2 |      1 | The Art Spirit                  | Robert Henry          |
|  3 |      1 | Art & Fear                      | David Bayles          |
|  4 |      1 | How Pictures Work               | Molly Bang            |
|  5 |      1 | Imaginative Realism             | James Gurney          |
|  6 |      2 | A Walk To Remember              | Nicholas Sparks       |
|  7 |      2 | An Old Fashioned Girl           | Louisa May Alcott     |
|  8 |      3 | The Rest Is Noise               | Alex Ross             |
|  9 |      3 | It Still Moves                  | Amanda Petrusich      |
| 10 |      3 | Chronicles                      | Bob Dylan             |
| 11 |      3 | Dream Boogie                    | Peter Guralnick       |
| 12 |      3 | Escaping The Delta              | Robert Johnson        |
| 13 |      4 | Atlas Shrugged                  | Ayn Rand              |
| 14 |      4 | Anthem                          | Ayn Rand              |
| 15 |      4 | Sons and Lovers                 | D.H. Lawrence         |
| 16 |      4 | Henderson the Rain King         | Saul Bellow           |
| 17 |      5 | The Art of Computer Programming | Donald Knuth          |
| 18 |      5 | The Art of Unix Programming     | Eric Raymond          |
| 19 |      5 | Free Software, Free Society     | Richard M. Stallman   |
| 20 |      5 | Database System Concepts        | Abraham Silberschatz  |
| 21 |      5 | 3ds Max 2008 in Simple Steps    | Kognet Solutions Inc. |
+----+--------+---------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: subqueries are slow, but: `SELECT t.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books WHERE cat_id = t.cat_id) as books_count FROM bookcatname t ORDER BY t.category ASC` and echo `books_count`

Comment: What does `bookcatname.id` do???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use JOIN opertaion on tables "bookcatname" and "books" to get the total count for each category.

```
SELECT A.cat_id as cat_id, count(A.cat_id) as cnt, B.category as cat_name
FROM books A, bookcatname B
WHERE A.cat_id=B.cat_id
GROUP BY A.cat_id
```

**Check demo on :** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73eb29/13

Modify your following part of index.php file:

`$res_query = mysql_query("SELECT A.cat_id as cat_id, count(A.cat_id) as cnt, B.category as cat_name FROM books A, bookcatname B WHERE A.cat_id=B.cat_id GROUP BY A.cat_id");`

`while ($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_query) )`
`{`

`echo '<a` `href="page.php?cat_id='.$category['cat_id'].'">'.$category['category'].'('.$category['cnt'].')</a><br />';`
`}`

Comment: Singh,
Thanks, but when I used your code I got the this error message above each category,

Notice: Undefined index: category in C:\xampp\htdocs\books2\index.php on line 27

Comment: change query to  $res_query = mysql_query("SELECT A.cat_id as cat_id, count(A.cat_id) as cnt, B.category as category FROM books A, bookcatname B WHERE A.cat_id=B.cat_id GROUP BY A.cat_id");

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.cat_id as cat_id, count(A.cat_id) as cnt, B.category as cat_name
FROM books A, bookcatname B
WHERE A.cat_id=B.cat_id
GROUP BY A.cat_id
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT A.cat_id as cat_id, count(A.cat_id) as cnt, B.category as cat_name
    FROM books A, bookcatname B
    WHERE A.cat_id=B.cat_id
    GROUP BY A.cat_id";
$res_query = mysql_query($sql);

while ($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_query) )
{
  echo '<a href="page.php?cat_id='.$category['cat_id'].'">'.$category['cat_name'].'</a><br />';
}

?>
```

Comment: I'm new to php language and would appreciate if you could tell me where to put this code.

Comment: It is showing the number of items next to the categories but the links are not working and getting the following error as well, Notice: Undefined index: cat_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\books2\index.php on line 27

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to complicate things since you are starting to learn PHP and MySQL. There are a lot of ways to achieve what you want but I will hand you a simple solution with your problem.

You can try changing your code from:

```
while ($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_query) )
{
  echo '<a href="page.php?cat_id='.$category['cat_id'].'">'.$category['category'].'</a><br />';
}
```

To:

```
while($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_query))
{
  $categoryID = $category['cat_id'];

  $queryCount = mysql_query("SELECT     COUNT(id) AS total
                             FROM       books
                             WHERE      cat_id = '$categoryID'");

  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryCount);

  echo '<a href="page.php?cat_id=' . $category['cat_id'] . '">' . $category['category'] . ' (' . $row['total'] . ')</a><br />';

  // Note: Please try to var_dump($row) and look if $row['total'] contains the number of books under on that category.
}
```

That's all and Enjoy learning...

Answer (score -1):

Try using SQL code that will count and group the items.
I am sure this code will work but it is UN-TESTED.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt,category
FROM books
LEFT JOIN bookcatname ON books.cat_id = bookcatname.cat_id
GROUP BY category
```

Then in your php code you will use something like this:

```
while ($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_query) )
{
  echo '<a href="page.php?cat_id='.$category['cat_id'].'">'.$category['category'].'('.$category['cnt'].')</a><br />';
}
```

**EDIT**
You will add this code to where you load the categories.

Comment: @JannetMackenzie If I were you I would use the inner join instead of selected from both tables for performance reasons.

Comment: It is showing the number of items next to the categories but the links are not working and getting the following error as well,

Notice: Undefined index: cat_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\books2\index.php on line 27

Comment: My downvote - only because this is a LEFT JOIN (and I would use a LEFT JOIN), so you have to be careful what you count!

Comment: @Strawberry Okay but the left join is there because what happens when you have other IDs in your books table but no corresponding record in book category table ? You would still want to display the category it would be better to `IFNULL` the category name.

Comment: @JacquesKoekemoer Yes. The LEFT JOIN *should* be there. Here, I'll edit your answer...